# AutoHotkey send without replacement

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotkey. Is there a way of using "Send" without getting the previously wirtten Hotstring replaced?
So if I want to use the Hotkey System it always overrides the System with the text I set after "Send". But how can I achive that it is just appending my Send text to the hotstring?

Comment: Please clarify. Post the code you're using, point out what isn't working. As it stands, I don't understand the question and more info will help.

Answer (score 0):

Send, Hotstring Rest of Things You Want to Say

Comment: Yeah but I think it would be faster without replacing my hotstrings just appending the text I want to send.

Comment: Faster? Your objection is that it is taking too long?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mistaken in what you're trying to say or how you're using `Send`, as it doesn't replace previously written hotstrings. If you post an example of what you're saying, it will be easier to help. Also, what do you mean when you say "Hotkey System"?

Helpful info from the online documentation, [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) & [Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

**EDIT** (per your comment below):

I understand what you're saying now. This is the default way that hotstrings work and has nothing to do with using the `Send` command. If you want to keep the activating text in a hotstring, you need to use the `B0` option. Something like this:

```
:*B0:System::.out.println()
```

Note that the `*` makes it so you don't need to type a period after "system". If you want it to work that way instead, remove the asterisk.

Comment: ::System::
Send, out.println()
return - This is my code but I if i run it and type in System. it replaces the System text and in my google search bar for example is not System.out.println but only .out.println. However, i want it to be appended to the hotstring text.

Comment: @nookyi change `::System:: Send, System.out.println() return`

Comment: @Yane That is the same as J.G.'s answer. OP mentioned preferring not to do it that way.